# Combining assert statement and instanceof pattern matching

Tags: java, pattern-matching, assert, instanceof

In Java 19, I'm trying to use `instanceof` pattern matching inside an `assert` statement.
I would expect the matched type would be available after the statement, but the Java compiler does not recognize the new variable.

We create a variable `Object obj`, and we cannot know whether it contains an `Integer` or a `String`.
We pass the variable to two test methods.

```java
public class AssertPatternMatching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = args.length == 0 ? Integer.valueOf(42) : "Hello";

        afterAssert(obj);
        insideMessage(obj);
    }
```

In method `afterAssert()`, we assert that `obj` is a `String`, and bind the string to the new variable `str` via `instanceof` pattern matching.
I would expect `str` to be known and usable in the next line.
However, the compiler does not know symbol `str`.

```java
    private static void afterAssert(Object obj) {
        assert obj instanceof String str;
        str.length(); // javac: cannot find symbol variable str
    }
```

In method `insideMessage()`, we use a convoluted `assert` statement to check that `obj` is *not* a `String`. If it would be, the assertion fails, and we can provide a message.
As the `instanceof` check is negated, pattern matched `str` variable *should* be available for the error message.
However, the compiler again does not know symbol `str`.

```java
    private static void insideMessage(Object obj) {
        assert !(obj instanceof String str) : "Is a string: " + str.length();
        // line above: javac: cannot find symbol variable str
        obj.hashCode();
    }
```

It works if we replace `assert` statements with `if`:

```java
private static void afterAssertIf(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof String str) {
        str.length();
    } else {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}

private static void insideMessageIf(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof String str)) {
        obj.hashCode();
    } else {
        throw new AssertionError("Is a string: "+ str.length());
    }
}
```

The *insideMessage()* example is really an edge case, so I understand it's not supported.
I would have expected *afterAssert()* to work, however.
Is this a deliberate design choice or a bug?
If deliberate, what's the rationale?

Complete code at https://gist.github.com/enikao/57bb1b10ce3126494ec4baa2bc7db2df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` statements are *only* executed when assertions are enabled with `-ea`. Without `-ea`, the code is *not* executed, therefore the variable is never assigned/does not exist (this is the default).

```
private static void afterAssert(Object obj) {
    assert obj instanceof String;
    ((String) str).length();
}
```

Because the compiler cannot know if the `assert` statement will be executed, it cannot rely on variables declared within the statement to be available outside of the statement (because the statement might never have been executed).

Comment: `-ea` is a run-time flag, right? That should not affect the compiler?

Comment: Yes, @werkderk, `-ea` is a runtime flag.  So no, the compiler's behavior cannot anticipate the value provided.  But on the other hand, the compiled code must work when `-ea` is *not* provided, in which case the `instanceof` is not executed.  It follows that the scope of the pattern-matched identifier cannot extend outside the `assert` statement.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger, makes sense. So in theory my convoluted _insideMessage()_ example should work, as the message expression is only evaluated if the assertion fails.
But nobody would write such an assert (hopefully!)

Comment: @werkderk first of all, assertions should not applied to parameters. Assertions are meant to check invariants the code is supposed to maintain and incoming parameters are the opposite of that. The standard idiom is an explicit check rejecting illegal arguments with an `IllegalArgumentException`. The instanceof pattern matching works smoothly with the idiomatic approach. It would be logical if your example in `insideMessage` worked but as discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75679239/2711488) only constructs named by the JLS explicitly “should work”. And assert is not among them.